# Excel VBA: Hide rows based on a formula; erroring on cell being blank

Tags: excel, vba

Here's the code I put in.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ActiveSheet.Activate
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("G17"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Target.Value
        Case Is = "Yes": Rows("21:27").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case Is <> "Yes": Rows("21:27").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case Is = "": Rows("21:27").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    
        End Select
    End If
    End Sub
```

What I was expecting was that if Cell G17 says anything other than "Yes", rows 21-27 will be hidden.

It works unless I try and delete the contents of the cell.  If I delete the contents of the cell, I get a Run-time error '13': Type mismatch.

Help!

Comment: `Select Case Target.Value` ---> `Select Case Me.Range("G17").Value`?

Comment: Btw your third condition is redundant.

Comment: @BigBen that was it!! Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

- Activesheet is activated, `ActiveSheet.Activate` is useless
- Validate the changed cell with `Target.Address = "$G$17"`

Please try.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$G$17" Then
        Rows("21:27").EntireRow.Hidden = Not (Target.Value = "Yes")
    End If
End Sub
```